# How to ESP32 Ethernet access HTTPS?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I'm want to send data using ethernet on https, i'm read exmpale [EthernetHttpClient_SSL](https://github.com/khoih-prog/EthernetWebServer_SSL) but not work. How to Solve this?

This my code:

```
char server = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
#define SSL_PORT 443
int port = 8080;
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetHttpClient_SSL.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
EthernetClient client;
EthernetHttpClient httpClient(client, server, SSL_PORT);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; 
  }
  Ethernet.init(5);
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    for (;;)
      ;
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("making GET request");
  httpClient.get("/posts/1");

  int statusCode = httpClient.responseStatusCode();
  String response = httpClient.responseBody();

  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  //  Serial.print("Response: ");
  //  Serial.println(response);
  Serial.println("Wait five seconds");
  delay(5000);
}
```

I'm get respon code: **-2**

Is there a simple and easy library to access https using Ethernet?

**If i'm access local server "localhost" success, i'm use client.print()**

Comment: where can I find EthernetHttpClient_SSL?

Comment: [EthernetHttpClient_SSL](https://github.com/khoih-prog/EthernetWebServer_SSL)